# Using np.argwhere to find the maximum in a matrix

Tags: python, numpy

I am trying to get the indices of the maximum value in a matrix, using argwhere function. I am using this syntax:

```
where = np.argwhere(np.argmax(matrix))
```

where matrix is the matrix i am using and i want where to be a tuple that gives me the coordinates of the maximum value.
But where prints as [0] and not (0,col) as i wanted (i just get the row but not the col)

Comment: I don't think you need the `np.argwhere` call. Does `np.argmax`, alone, not give you what you want?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`np.argmax(arr)` by default, returns the index of the maximum value into the *flattened array*, `arr.ravel()`.

To obtain the index of the maximum value of `arr` itself, use [`np.unravel_index`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.1/reference/generated/numpy.unravel_index.html):

```
In [15]: np.random.seed(2016); arr = np.random.randint(10, size=(2,3)); arr
Out[15]: 
array([[3, 7, 2],
       [3, 8, 4]])
In [17]: np.argmax(arr)
Out[17]: 4
In [18]: np.unravel_index(np.argmax(arr), arr.shape)
Out[18]: (1, 1)
```

Comment: Exactly what i needed!